# Manipulating a QStringList in C++

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, qstring

I have a `QStringList` named `filesToCopy` which contains the files name to copy.
I want to make this output:

> for %I in ("(", "C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.mp4",
>   "C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.srt", "C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.txt", ")",
>   "do copy %I", "C:\Users\Nins\Desktop\z")

to look like this:

> for %I in ("C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.mp4"
>   "C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.srt" "C:\Users\Nina\Documents\A.txt") do
>   copy %I "C:\Users\Nina\Desktop\z"

This is my code:

```
d->copyProcess = new QProcess(this);
QStringList copyProcessParameters;
Q_FOREACH(QString fileName, fileNames)
{
    d->totalFileSize += this->getSize(fileName);
    d->filesToCopy.append(fileName);
}

d->filesToCopy.append(")");
d->filesToCopy.prepend("(");
copyProcessParameters.append(d->filesToCopy);
copyProcessParameters.append("do copy %I");
copyProcessParameters.append(destinationDir);
copyProcessParameters.replaceInStrings("/","\\");
qDebug()<<"for %I in" << copyProcessParameters;
d->copyProcess->start("for %I in", copyProcessParameters);
```

Comment: Why do you make a system call to copy files? Why do you not use QFile to copy the files?

Comment: I don't want to use threads and without using threads the QFileCopy works synchronously which I don't want. @Mofi

Comment: Why don't you want to use threads? An external process is effectively another thread anyway. This appears to be an XY Problem. What is your real aim?

Answer (score 1):

Use [QStringList::join()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join) to create the list separated by a space.

And, to make things simple, you can use [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-12) or its overloads to create the desired string with replacements. That would be more straightforward to use and readable instead of a lot of `prepend()` and/or `append()` calls.

Here's an example:

```
const QString format { R"(for %I in (%1) do copy %I %2)" };

const auto command = format.arg( filesList, destinationDir );
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Azeem mentioned, you can use `join()` method:

```
auto l_files = fileNames.join(", ");
```

Also note that macro `Q_FOREACH` is currently (since Qt 5.7) discouraged and will be removed in a future version of Qt. You should use range-based loop from C++ standard:

```
for(auto& fileName : fileNames)
{
    doSomething(fileName);
}
```

If you want to iterate over const references you can use `qAsConst()`.